# Primefaces dialog doesnt show values

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, datatable

Hi i am new with primefaces and i have some problems with the values that are shown in my dataTable. I load data from my sql database and show this data in the dataTable. There is one colums called :"Comments", where is a button inside. If you click on this button a dialog is open up. Inside this dialog frame, there should be also some of the same values i show in the dataTable, but it doesnt work. I cant display the values in that dialog frame. I googled a lot and tried a lot but nothing helped. 
Here is xhtml:

```
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:dataTable value="#{gutachtenBean.daten}" var="auftrag"
            rowKey="#{gutachtenBean.daten}" selectionMode="multiple">

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:outputPanel>
                    <h:outputText value="Vorgangsliste"
                        style="position:relative; top: 4px; float:left;  font-size:14px" />
                    <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" style="margin-right:10px" />
                    <p:inputText style="width:150px" placeholder="Enter keyword" />
                </p:outputPanel>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column style="text-align:center"
                filterBy="#{auftrag.schadennummer}" headerText="Schadennummer"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                #{auftrag.schadennummer}
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:150px;text-align:center"
                filterBy="#{auftrag.vorgangsnummer}" headerText="Vorgangsnummer"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                #{auftrag.vorgangsnummer}
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:120px;text-align:center"
                filterBy="#{auftrag.kennzeichen}" headerText="Kennzeichen"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                #{auftrag.kennzeichen}
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:100px;text-align:center"
                filterBy="#{auftrag.kennzeichen}" headerText="Organisation">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectOneMenu>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.brands}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:column>

            <p:column style="width:220px;text-align:center"
                filterBy="#{auftrag.status}" headerText="Status"
                filterMatchMode="contains">
                #{auftrag.status}
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="SLA-Beginn"
                style="width:130px;text-align:center">
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="SLA-Laufzeit"
                style="width:130px;text-align:center">
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="SLA-Überschreitung"
                style="width:130px;text-align:center">
            </p:column>

            <p:column filterBy="#{auftrag.kennzeichen}"
                style="width:100px;text-align:center" headerText="Ampel">
                <f:facet name="filter">
                    <p:selectOneMenu>
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{dtFilterView.brands}" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </f:facet>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Kommentare"
                style="width:100px;text-align:center">
                <p:commandButton styleClass="viewbutton"
                    style="border-left:1px solid #666; height:20px;font-size:10px"
                    value="Open" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" />
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton styleClass="viewbutton" value="View"
            icon="ui-icon-search"
            style="border-left:1px solid #666;margin-top:10px"></p:commandButton>
    </h:form>
    <p:dialog header="Kommentar" widgetVar="dlg1" height="600px"
        width="900px">
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="#{auftrag.kommentar}"/>
        </h:form> 
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
```

Here is my Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="gutachtenBean")
@SessionScoped
public class GutachtenController implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8410541973590420821L;

    private DatabaseConnector connector = new DatabaseConnector();
    private List<GutachtenDaten> daten;

    public GutachtenController(){
        daten = connector.getAuftragsDaten();
    }

    public List<GutachtenDaten> getDaten() {
        return daten;
    }

    public void setDaten(List<GutachtenDaten> daten) {
        this.daten = daten;
    }
}


public class GutachtenDaten {

    private String schadennummer;
    private String kennzeichen;
    private String status;
    private String vorgangsnummer;
    private String kommentar;

    public String getSchadennummer() {
        return schadennummer;
    }

    public void setSchadennummer(String schadennummer) {
        this.schadennummer = schadennummer;
    }

    public String getKennzeichen() {
        return kennzeichen;
    }

    public void setKennzeichen(String kennzeichen) {
        this.kennzeichen = kennzeichen;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getVorgangsnummer() {
        return vorgangsnummer;
    }

    public void setVorgangsnummer(String vorgangsnummer) {
        this.vorgangsnummer = vorgangsnummer;
    }

    public String getKommentar() {
        return kommentar;
    }

    public void setKommentar(String kommentar) {
        this.kommentar = kommentar;
    }

}
```

**I dont understand why the values arent shown in the dialog frame. Please someone help!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#{auftrag}` is only available inside the table, during rendering. On click of the button, you must put the selected row in a bean variable, and display that in the dialog. 
Add something like this to `GutachtenController`

```
private GutachtenDaten selectedGD;

public GutachtenDaten getSelectedGD() {
    return this.selectedGD;
}

public void setSelectedGD(GutachtenDaten gd) {
    this.selectedGD = gd;
}

public void initSelectedGD(GutachtenDaten gd) {
    setSelectedGD(gd);
}
```

Change `Kommentare` button to

```
<p:commandButton styleClass="viewbutton"
                 style="border-left:1px solid #666; height:20px;font-size:10px"
                 value="Open" type="button" oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();" 
                 actionListener="#{gutachtenBean.initSelectedGD(auftrag)}" update="@widgetVar(dlg1)"/>
```

And change dialog to

```
<p:dialog header="Kommentar" widgetVar="dlg1" height="600px"
    width="900px">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{gutachtenBean.selectedGD.kommentar}"/>
    </h:form> 
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, but it doesnt work. First of all "oncomplete" doesnt even open up the dialog frame. only onclick opens it. second the values inside the dialog frame still isnt shown.

Comment: Did you check for errors on the server and client, when you use `oncomplete`? There is no reason it shouldn't work, except if there is some exception

Comment: I've edited my answer just to be sure. Add `initSelectedGD()` method to `GutachtenController`, and change button's action listener to `actionListener="#{gutachtenBean.initSelectedGD(auftrag)}"`. If you put a breakpoint in `initSelectedGD()`, does it enter the method?

Comment: Ive putted a logger to the initSelectedGD method but he doesnt log, means he doesnt even enter this method. are there any extra things i have to put for the actionListener? i use the actionListener in the commandButton but in my GutachtenController class isnt anything like the actionListener for the button.

Comment: Which JSF version are you using? This syntax works with JSF version > 2, if you are using some earlier version I will edit my answer, but in that case you should get at least some exception.

Comment: I think the version isnt the problem. I am working with 2.0.0. Ive putted an actionlistener to the button like on http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/button/commandButton.xhtml .
But he doesnt even do this!!!! so there is an other problem that blocks the communication. i really dont know what the problem could be.

Comment: OK i got it !! Your solution was right. i just added process="@this" to my commandButton and it works !!!!! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad to see you got it working, it's my fault it didn't come to my mind before. I learned the hard way (as you did now) that whenever action listener isn't called, you should add `process="@this"` :)